# How to access the program "create reset cd" when search function doesn't work

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-search, reset

I want to create backup media through a built in program in Windows 8.1. In the instructions it says that I should search for "reset" (or something similar; my OS and instructions are not in English). My goal is to create a reset CD for Windows 8.

How do I access a certain program when the search function doesn't work in Windows 8.1? My SearchIndexer.exe is completely gone and I cannot search for programs when I swipe in from the left and choose Search.

How do I access this program when I am unable to find it with a search?

Or if you think you know what program I'm looking for you can give me the path to it.

Answer (score 0):

**The Short Way**: Open the Run dialog (<kbd>Win</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd>) and type "recoverydrive" (elevation required).

You can also access the recovery drive creator through the GUI:

1. Open the Control Panel by going to the Desktop, opening the Charms bar, selecting Settings, and clicking Control Panel.
2. In the "View by" dropdown (upper-right corner of the window, below the search bar), select "Small icons"
3. Click "Recovery"
4. Click "Create a recovery drive"